# Getting error while executing SQLite command from application

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have this simple function in my application :

```
-(NSMutableArray *)SelectProductID:(NSMutableArray *)arr
{
    NSLog(@"----------------");

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSMutableArray *arrPordID = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    @try
    {

        //Get productID
        for(NSString *strSubProductID in arr)
        {


            NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ProductID FROM SubProducttable where SubProductID=%@",strSubProductID];

            const char *sql = [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){

                    char *dbString;

                    dbString = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
                    NSString *pID = (dbString) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:dbString] : @"";
                    [arrPordID addObject:pID];

                }

            }             

        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

        @throw exception;
    }
    @finally {

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    return arrPordID;

}
```

I am encountering a strange problem here. When application reaches `while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){`, loop is never entered. I don't know why. I executed the same query in SQLite manager (when application is not running). And I get result as a single one. The result I get is **2**. But here I am getting nothing.

And yes, I always close the database in SQLite manager whenever I run my application. I have also cleaned the application, restarted XCode, and removed the application from simulator. But no success.

Also I saw a strange thing during debugging. While debugging, `sqlite3_stmt *statement` is always skipped. Is this the reason I am not getting any result?

Comment: What type is your SubProductID in SubProducttable?

Comment: `sqlite3_errcode()` and `sqlite3_errmsg()` are your friends. Ask them for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried subproductId in single quotes?

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ProductID FROM SubProducttable where SubProductID='%@'",strSubProductID];
```

Comment: Very strange. I never have this problem. I never use single quotes and still everything is fine. Don't know why this time it didn't work..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlQuery = @"SELECT ProductID FROM SubProducttable where SubProductID=%@",strSubProductID;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, statement, -1, &sqlQuery, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(sqlQuery ) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Read the data and add to your array object
        }
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

}
sqlite3_close(database)
```

Comment: I have used separate function where I have opened and closed database. It is not the issue. Because before the above function I have a similar SQLite query in a function. It runs successfully.